# Fail to upload local CSV file with fetch() and fail to execute FileReader()

Tags: javascript, csv

I'm trying to manipulate a **local CSV file** with JavaScript. My purpose is to display datas from my CSV on my website, like we were using an external API in JSON format for example.

```js
const csvLocalFile =
  "http://XXX/.../file.csv";

const openFile = async () => {
  const csv = await fetch(csvLocalFile).then();
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    let text = reader.result;
    filecontent = text.replace("", "");
  };
  reader.readAsText(csv.files[0]);
};

openFile();
```

Chrome display this error :

**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')**

When I delete "[0]" from "reader.readAsText(csv.files[0])", I have this message error :

**TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.**

Comment: You dont seem to be parsing the response as csv, and why use `await` with `then`?

Comment: What's the empty `.then()` there for? I'd remove that for starters.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I tried using .then((res) => res.JSON()) but it doesn't work so I let empty. The rest of the code is an answer to another question in Stackoverflow about this.

Comment: even if I remove the ".then()" the problem remains the same: I can not read my CSV with the FileReader() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A empty `.then()` isn't the problem, turns out it works fine without a fn. but you should remove it regardless.
2. The FileReader can't read Response objects, only File & Blobs...
3. You say that you try to read a local file, but yet you use `fetch` to get a remote file, so what is it that your really trying to do? it's unclear of how to help you...
4. a csv isn't valid json data, so you can't use `.then((res) => res.JSON())`
5. beside `res.JSON()` is wrong, it should be all lowercased... `res.json()`
6. The FileReader is considered legacy so you no longer need it... use `await blob.text()` instead

here are two examples of how to read 1 remote file using fetch

```js
// Simulate getting a file from eg a file input or drag and drop
const file = new File(['id,name\n10,bob'], 'file.csv', { type: 'text/csv' })
// Simulate a remote location to get the csv from
const url = URL.createObjectURL(file)

const csvLocalFile = url // http://XXX/.../file.csv

const openFile = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(csvLocalFile)
  const text = await response.text()
  console.log(text)
}

openFile()
```

...and another with a actual local file selected from a user input

```js
const fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput')

fileInput.onchange = async () => {
  const file = fileInput.files[0]
  const text = await file.text()
  console.log(text)
}

// ignore code below this line...

// Create a dummy file that we can use to change the file input with...
const dummyFile = new File(['id,name\n10,bob'], 'file.csv', { type: 'text/csv' })
// Used for creating a new FileList in a round-about way
const b = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || new DataTransfer()
b.items.add(dummyFile)
// simulate picking a file
fileInput.files = b.files
fileInput.onchange()
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileInput">
```

Comment: thank you verry much, the first answer works very well. The other is not work for me because I have the CSV file in my computer, I do not need to use a HTML input. I was looking to display datas from my own local file on the console.